# Django Queryset filtering in comparison to timezone.now returns unexpected results

Tags: python, django, datetime, pytz

I have a model, whose "published" instances I want to be the ones with a `publish_date` that is in the past.

```
# settings.py

USE_TZ = True

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Athens'


# models.py

class Publishable(models.Model):
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(
        _('publish date'), blank=True, null=True)

    objects = PublishableManager()


# managers.py

class PublishableQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def published(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return self.exclude(
            Q(date_published__gt=now) | Q(date_published__isnull=True))


class PublishableManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return PublishableQuerySet(
            self.model, using=self.db).prefetch_related()

    def published(self):
        return self.get_queryset().published()
```

So I have a `Publishable` instance in the db whose `date_published` is in the past and which should be fetched when I try to fetch the "published" instances. It is not fetched however, even though when actually comparing its `date_published` with `timezone.now()` it is correctly said to be in the past. For example:

```
from django.utils import timezone as t

p = Publishable.objects.latest('date_published')
p.date_published == datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 14, 5, tzinfo=<UTC>) # -> True 
t.now() == datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 14, 6, 6, 481400, tzinfo=<UTC>) # -> True 
t.now() > p.date_published()  # -> True, which is expected

p in Publishable.objects.published()  # -> False... why?
```

Some extra info:

- When `date_published` is about 50mins or more ago, the instance is fetched
- <del>When I remove `.pyc` files the instance is fetched</del>
- I am using Django 1.8.11 and I have `pytz` installed

So, why isn't the instance fetched if the comparison test with the current time is passed? What am I missing here?

---

**Edit**

The above is in a dev environment (with `SQLite` and django's dev server), but the "missing published instance" has been witnessed in the production environment as well (which has `MySQL` unfortunately).

The `.pyc` phenomenon I mentioned above is somewhat incorrect. The behavior is corrected when I **restart the dev server**.

Something I noticed, which is clearly related to this, is that if I try to `print` in `PublishableQuerySet.published()`, it's not called (i.e. no `print`ing takes place) most of the time, so basically... the comparison to `timezone.now()` seems to not take place.

Comment: The `.pyc` thing is especially surprising. Why don't you look at the actual database queries being sent to see what the difference is? If the results are different then the queries must be different. Also, tag this with the database you're using.